# RestTemplate with Basic Auth in Spring 3.1

Tags: java, spring, restful-authentication, resttemplate, apache-httpclient-4.x

We were using RestTemplate with xml configuration in Spring 3.0 and it was working perfectly fine.

```
<bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient"> 
    <!--  <constructor-arg ref="httpClientParams"/> --> 
</bean>

<bean id="httpClientFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory"> 
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClient"/> 
</bean>  

  <bean id="restTemplate" name="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate" autowire-candidate="true">
        <constructor-arg ref="httpClientFactory" />

    <property name="messageConverters"> 
        <list> 
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            </bean> 
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/> 
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
        </list> 
    </property>
  </bean>
```

But, when we are trying to migrate to Spring 3.1 release CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory class is deprecated and also commons HttpClient is not used anymore.

I was trying to set up similar config using HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory class and Apache HttpClient, but not getting how can I set the Credential Provider.

We want the httpclient with basic auth.  Has anybody done this or any pointers would be great help.  Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was able to finally get this working.  Not sure whether it is optimal, as this the first solution which worked for me.

`

```
<!-- Credentials provider needed by apache default http client -->
<bean id="credentialProvider" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider" />

<!-- Used to invoke a method in BasicCredentialsProvider.  This has to be done this way as BasicCredentialsProvider does not take 
provider and credentials in constructor or setter method.  It has to set by invoking setCredentials() method and passing two arguments -->  
<bean id="methodInvoke" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject"><ref local="credentialProvider" /> </property>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="setCredentials"> </property>
    <property name="arguments"  >
        <list>
            <ref local="authScope" />
            <ref local="credentials" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Authorization scope for accessing restful service.  Since we want this template to be used for everything, we are setting up it with defaults -->
<bean id="authScope" class="org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope">
    <constructor-arg name="host"><null /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg><value>-1</value> </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg><null /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg><null /></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- Username and Password Credentials to access restful service -->
<bean id="credentials" class="org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials">
    <constructor-arg name="userName"><value>xxx</value></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="password"><value>xxx</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- Client factory which uses Apache HttpClient implementation.  Note that it DO NOT use apache commons httpclient -->
<bean id="httpClientFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory"> 
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClient"/> 
</bean>

<bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient">
    <property name="credentialsProvider" ref="credentialProvider"/>
</bean>

<!-- Rest template for Spring 3.1. Used HttpClientFactory to make request -->
  <bean id="restTemplate" name="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate" autowire-candidate="true">
        <constructor-arg ref="httpClientFactory" />

    <property name="messageConverters"> 
        <list> 
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            </bean> 
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/> 
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
        </list> 
    </property>
  </bean>`
```

Comment: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient is deprecated.

Comment: How to perform a preemptive authentication with this configuration using org.apache.http 4.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to work this out with Spring 4 RestTemplate

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="httpClientFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="httpClientFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
         <constructor-arg ref="httpClient" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="httpClient" factory-bean="httpClientBuilder" factory-method="build" />

    <bean id="httpClientBuilder" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder" factory-method="create">
        <property name="defaultRequestConfig" ref="requestConfig" />
        <property name="defaultCredentialsProvider" ref="credentialProvider"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="requestConfig" factory-bean="requestConfigBuilder" factory-method="build" />

    <bean id="requestConfigBuilder" class="org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig" factory-method="custom">
        <property name="socketTimeout" value="${MILLISEC`enter code here`ONDS}" /> 
        <property name="connectTimeout" value="${MILLISECONDS}" /> 
    </bean> 

<bean id="credentials" class="org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials">
        <constructor-arg value="${USER}" />
        <constructor-arg value="${PASSWORD}" />
        <constructor-arg value="" />
        <constructor-arg value="${DOMAIN}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="credentialProvider" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider" />

    <!-- This is used to invoke a method in BasicCredentialsProvider.  This has to be done this way as BasicCredentialsProvider does not take 
    provider and credentials in constructor or setter method.  It has to set by invoking setCredentials() method and passing two arguments -->  
    <bean id="methodInvoke" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="credentialProvider" /> 
        <property name="targetMethod" value="setCredentials" />
        <property name="arguments"  >
            <list>
                <ref bean="authScope" />
                <ref bean="credentials" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Authorization scope for accessing restful service. Since we want this template to be used for everything, we are setting up it with defaults -->
    <bean id="authScope" class="org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope">
        <constructor-arg name="host"><null /></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg><value>-1</value> </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg><null /></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg><null /></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```