# Basic Authentication with RestTemplate (3.1)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, basic-authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x, resttemplate

I am trying to reproduce the following curl command using Java:

```
curl -v -u user:pass http://myapp.com/api
```

This command returns some JSON data.

My buggy Java implementation is as follows:

```
@Test
public void callTest() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = createRestTemplate("user", "pass");
    URI uri = new URI("http://myapp.com/api");
    String res = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
}

private static RestTemplate createRestTemplate(String username, String password) {

    UsernamePasswordCredentials cred = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
    BasicCredentialsProvider cp = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    cp.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, cred);
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    client.setCredentialsProvider(cp);
    ClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
    // set the media types properly
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Yet, when I execute the test, it returns a `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized` exception.

When logging in `DEBUG`, I see no information about the authentication...

What am I doing wrong while setting the authentication credentials?

Answer (score 13):

Instantiating using

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

doesn't exist anymore and class `DefaultHttpClient` is deprecated from **HttpComponents HttpClient** from **version 4.3**. So other answer are either invalid or deprecated. Here is my version, I wrote this class for rest requests which require basic authentication:

```
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class RestClient extends RestTemplate {
    public RestClient(String username, String password) {
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(null, -1),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
        setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));
    }
}
```

Then use it like, for example:

```
RestClient restClient = new RestClient("username", "password");

String result = restClient.postForObject(...
```

Comment: Thanks! The only one working (without using depreciated methods) on this page for me.

Comment: Extending RestTemplate to do this is the wrong approach. Configure it to do what you need (in Spring XML or Java config), rather than subclassing it.

Comment: Nice example there, Good point made by @TedPennings.. thank you both.

Comment: I was already creating a RestTemplate as needed, so I didn't need to subclass like this - I simply used the provided code to set my credentials. Good work.

Comment: I tried this implementation to POST to the Jenkins buildWithParameters URL for a particular job and it keeps failing with a 403 indicating that the operation did not work. Using the same URL, user, and password with curl and this works without a problem.

Any clues as to why this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

I do something like this - and it has worked for me:

```
private RestTemplate createRestTemplate(String username, String password) {
    return new RestTemplate(this.createSecureTransport(username, password));
}

protected ClientHttpRequestFactory createSecureTransport(String username, String password){
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username,password);
    client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);
    CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory commons = new CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);

    return commons;
}
```

It is used here: [Reference Code](https://github.com/cts2/cts2-framework/blob/master/core/src/main/java/edu/mayo/cts2/framework/core/client/Cts2RestClient.java)

Comment: That's with the old HTTPClient api. I use the 4.x, in which the CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory does not exist any more.

Answer (score 1):

httpclient v4.0 not Support Preemptive authentication

Look this : 
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?123385-Preemptive-Basic-Authentication-with-RestTemplate

In spring Source found this solution.

It works for me.

Look this : [RestTemplate with Basic Auth in Spring 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048812/resttemplate-with-basic-auth-in-spring-3-1)

Comment: None of the other answers worked for me. The only way I got it to work  was using preemptive authentication. http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/114029-preemptive-basic-authentication-with-resttemplate

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on the one by @kevinpeterson, but with a rewrite to use the updated Apache HTTP Client.

```
RestTemplate createRestTemplate(String username, String password, String host, int port ) {
    return new RestTemplate(this.createSecureTransport( username, password, host, port ));
}

ClientHttpRequestFactory createSecureTransport( String username, String password, String host, int port ){
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials( username, password );
    client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials( new AuthScope( host, port ), credentials );
    return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
```

Comment: At least with Spring Framework 3.2.3 and httpclient 4.2.3, I couldn't get this code above to work.  I tried it with both specified AuthScope  and AuthScope.ANY, but i think it won't work.  The link from Makoton explains why and has a better solution.

Comment: Don't know what issue you're experiencing, but I'm using this code successfully with Spring Framework 3.2.4 and httpclient 4.2.1. I doubt that the minor version differences are the problem, but who knows.