# Multiple RestTemplate and CredentialProviders not working well in Spring

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, resttemplate

I have an application that is using a RestTemplate with CreditialProvider exactly the way it is described in the accepted solution of this StackOverflow entry ([RestTemplate with Basic Auth in Spring 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048812/resttemplate-with-basic-auth-in-spring-3-1)).

This worked just fine while I had a single service set up with this.
However I recently added a new RestTemplate to be used by another service, with different username and password, and for the life of it can not get it to make the Rest requests using a username and password. All the bean ids are different, so there can not be any issues there.

When stepping through the Spring startup it simply seems to attache an empty set of credentials to the HttpClient.

Any suggestions or pitfalls I should consider when using this solution? Anything singleton (pools) that cause messing up this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally figured it out. This was a Spring thing that was one of those annoying ones that are tough to find.

The core of the problem was this part of the solution referred to in my question:

```
<!-- Used to invoke a method in BasicCredentialsProvider.  This has to be done this way as BasicCredentialsProvider does not take 
provider and credentials in constructor or setter method.  It has to set by invoking setCredentials() method and passing two arguments -->  
<bean id="methodInvoke" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject"><ref local="credentialProvider" /> </property>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="setCredentials"> </property>
    <property name="arguments"  >
        <list>
            <ref local="authScope" />
            <ref local="credentials" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

When creating the 2nd set of Spring definition for my Rest service, i copied and pasted, not realizing the duplicate id value of "methodInvoke" would cause this to only be run 1 time.

Bottom line: don't give a bean an id if it doesn't need one - it can only give you grieve. In this case, it's not referenced anywhere else since it's just a MethodInvoker.